# Exception Error Codes in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Is there a list of .NET Exception error codes around?

I get these error codes with a couple of `HttpExceptions`,

```
0x80070040
0x800703E3
```

And require to know the difference between the two errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are not .NET Exception Error codes. They are Windows HRESULT codes.

- 0x80070040 is "The specified network name is no longer available."
- 0x800703E3 is "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request."

You can find these by using Tools->Error Lookup in Visual Studio.

Comment: and, as it happens, these specific codes aren't even listed in the link I provide.

Comment: Thanks guys. Realise it was an easy question. But appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx) - these are in fact `HRESULT` error codes, which [`HttpException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception.aspx) exposes.